# Extending Activity to implement an Idle timer

Tags: android

I've developed some code that implements a timer - it ticks every second and after x seconds of not touching the display the "idle" activity is launched.
However, this needs to be implemented for about 8 activities... I could copy and paste the relevant code to each activity but that's not an elegant solution.

So, I started to create my custom activity "TimedActivity" to extend Activity. The other activities that I'll need to implement can then implement "TimedActivity".

However, how can my TimedActivity detect onTouch events ?

this is what I have so far:

```
public class TimedActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{
    private LinearLayout mLinearLayoutMain;//intended to be the root node in the XML
    private Timer mTimerSeconds;
    private int mIntIdleSeconds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //NO setContentView() 

        mIntIdleSeconds=0;

        mTimerSeconds = new Timer();
        mTimerSeconds.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                timerSecondsCounter();
            }
        }, 0, 1000);

        //the whole screen should become sensitive to touch
        //HOWEVER, there's no View established
        mLinearLayoutMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
        //mLinearLayoutMain remains null, so next line excepts
        mLinearLayoutMain.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        if (mTimerSeconds != null)
        {
            mTimerSeconds.cancel();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        mIntIdleSeconds=0;
        return false;//do not consume
    }

    private void timerSecondsCounter()
    {
        mIntIdleSeconds++;

        if (mIntIdleSeconds == Constants.MAX_IDLE_TIME_SECONDS)
        {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(this, what.ever.com.Idle.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

the subsequent activity to use this will then use:

```
public class ActivitySelect extends TimedActivity
{
}
```

and the xml for the view would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main">

<!-- MORE STUFF --->

</LinearLayout>
```

I feel that I am close, but what do I need to do to get this working ?

**EDIT:
This is what I ended up implementing...**

```
public class TimedActivity extends Activity
{
    //member variables
    private Timer mTimerSeconds;
    private int mIntIdleSeconds;
    private boolean mBoolInitialized=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        if (mTimerSeconds != null)
        {
            mTimerSeconds.cancel();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onTouch()
    {
        mIntIdleSeconds=0;
    }

    /** start the idle timer */
    public void startIdleTimer()
    {
        if (mBoolInitialized == false)
        {
            mBoolInitialized = true;

            //initialize idle counter
            mIntIdleSeconds=0;

            //create timer to tick every second
            mTimerSeconds = new Timer();
            mTimerSeconds.schedule(new TimerTask()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    timerSecondsCounter();
                }
            }, 0, 1000);
        }
    }

    /** called every second to count idle time and to update clock on Welcome screen */
    private void timerSecondsCounter()
    {

        mIntIdleSeconds++;

        if (mIntIdleSeconds == Constants.MAX_IDLE_TIME_SECONDS)
        {
            //idle time long enough to launch standby activity
            final Intent intent = new Intent(this, what.ever.com.Idle.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

}
```

To use this ActivityTimed, within your launched Activity do:

```
public class ActivitySelect extends TimedActivity implements OnTouchListener
{
    //UI references
    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);//triggers TimedActivity::onCreate()
        setContentView(R.layout.select);

        //get references to all of your widgets
        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.select_linearlayout_main);

        //set your widgets as touchable
        mLinearLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

        //start the idle timer
        super.startIdleTimer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        //this is very important here ;-)
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        final int actionPerformed = event.getAction();

        //reset idle timer
        // put this here so that the touching of empty space is captured too
        //  it seems that LinearLayout doesn't trigger a MotionEvent.ACTION_UP or MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
        if (actionPerformed == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            super.onTouch();
        }

        return false;//do not consume event!
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this timeout to expire somekind of session, or send user to login screen? If it is i've encountered the same problem and have a different solution.

Comment: yes, once the timeout happens a different activity is automatically launched - i.e. login screen, screen saver, etc... some idle screen

Comment: Then you can avoid this method, by using default attributes: finishOnTaskLaunch on all but Login (login activity cannot be finished and has to be on stack.

You can also detect if the screen was turned off, and send immediatly to login screen.

Comment: NeTeInStEiN, if you have time, could you demonstrate your solution with code snippets? I have searched for a while and a lot of people want to implement some kind of idle/timeout mechanism for activities - it would be helpful to see your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** OK, what I tried to suggest earlier wasn't quite what I meant...

In the `onCreate()` method of `ActivitySelect` (for example) put the code...

```
setContentView(/* Id of layout file for ActivitySelect */);
mLinearLayoutMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(/* Id of LinearLayout for ActivitySelect */);
```

This will mean `ActivitySelect` will set its content view and also set the inherited `mLinearLayoutMain` member to the view.

In `onStart()` for `TimedActivity` put...

```
mLinearLayoutMain.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

You might also want to use `@Override` on the `onTouch()` method in `TimedActivity`

Comment: whilst eating lunch I thought it might be worth a go to pass a reference of LinearLayout to the super class (TimedActivity) by implementing a function in TimedActivity such as "setViewRoot". Then call it with super.setViewRoot(reference to LinearLayout);    I'll try it after lunch.

Comment: What I ended up doing is not passing the reference of the LinearLayout to the TimedActivity at all. Instead, I only implemented the timing logic in TimedActivity and a void onTouch(). This onTouch() is responsible for resetting the counter to 0. Then, ActivitySelect extends TimedActivity implements OnTouchListener. 
All the onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) callbacks then call super.onTouch(); This works great and also keeps the code decoupled as much as possible.

Comment: I'll accept your answer because it will probably work - I had the same thought around lunch time but I prefer my current implementation.

Comment: @Someone: OK, that's cool - obviously you need to go with the solution which works best for you. Thanks for the accept.